# jQuery - Building an AutoResizing TextArea that Doesn't Flash on Resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been working to create an auto resizing textarea (like on FB) that resizes as you type. There are a few plugins out there. Problem is they all are only 99% there. What's missing is:

- On Resize the textarea flashes (on return/enter)
- On Paste there is a delay

Please take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/uzjdC/3/

Any ideas why it flashes on resize? Type some text, then press Enter to see it..

Thanks

Comment: doesn't flash on ff 4 beta. It might be a browser specific issue.

Comment: I'm on Chrome. will ry on FF now. FB's growing textarea's don't flash on chrome...

Comment: I confirm, no flash in FF but Chrome and Safari do flash... What could be causing that?

Comment: What browser does it "flash?" not in chrome...

Comment: Doesn't flash on Chrome for me. (10.0.634.0)

Comment: @Anonymous: I'm sorry, *what*? (I'm not being facile, I genuinely have no idea what you mean in your comment).

Comment: IE8 flashes. FF3 doesn't. (and as I said before, Chrome doesn't) Can't test Safari at the moment. P.S. David...100% agree. Reported him...no idea what he's talking about.

Comment: @David- Don't use JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @AnApprentice it only grows on an enter?

Comment: it grows on enter, paste or type but the issue is it flashes when you press enter. type some text in and then press Enter a few times, you'll see it in Chrome.

Comment: @Anonymous, that part I got; but I don't understand the reasoning behind the suggestion.

Comment: @clif I didn't know there was a v10, I'm using the latest on the Mac, 8.0.552.334

Comment: Ah. All of my tests were Windows. Don't have a Mac in the office. I would suggest taking the code apart.  The add-on you are using to grow the field seems slightly too complicated. My instinct is you can probably simplify it and might find the offending action in the process.  I don't know...would be good for learning anyway.

Comment: @Anonymous the suggestion that AnApprentice shouldn't 'use JavaScript libraries'?

Comment: @AnApprentice Please don't listen to anonymous. There's a few reasons why you shouldn't use jQuery (or other JS libraries), but they're all situational and none of them apply to you.

Comment: @AnApprentice Well I was right that you can do what you're trying to do with a lot less JS, but ultimately my "solution" still flashes (worse than before) and doesn't feel quite as smooth. :) Here it is anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/9aTJp/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yahoo! I've found a solution! Your example intrigued me very much, [that's why I decided to play around in jsFiddle to try to fix your flashing issue](http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/2D8Kf/). The flashing is due to the fact that the `TextArea` has 'to much text' and some scrolling occurs. The `keyup` event isn't equipped to beat this scrollbar, but... the `scroll` event is!

Html:

```
<textarea id="tst" rows="1" cols="40">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque interdum porttitor neque eget consequat. Sed faucibus purus vitae felis facilisis bibendum.</textarea>
```

Css:

```
textarea{    
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    padding:10px;
}
```

<strike>To do the upsizing I'm using the `rows` attribute of the TextArea. I've written it into a function:</strike> I'm up-sizing the area with this function:

```
//resize text area
function resizeTextArea(elem){

    elem.height(1); 
    elem.scrollTop(0);
    elem.height(elem[0].scrollHeight - elem[0].clientHeight + elem.height());
}
```

Now we only need to bind the resize:

```
//inital resize - on document load
resizeTextArea($('#tst'));

//bind events
$('#tst').bind('scroll keyup', function(){
    resizeTextArea($(this));
});
```

Note: no flashing occurs! Why? Because the use of the `scoll` event! You can try the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/2D8Kf/

**Good luck!**

**Edit**: Changed the code in the jsFiddle example to support schemes that have dynamicly added textareas. [Check also this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768691/how-bind-the-scroll-event-on-a-live).

Comment: Ow... and there is no paste delay as well :P

Comment: Thats good. Tried it out. Couple issues though. It doesn't work with max-height, also why rely on rows, I think CSS would be a lot better right? Also, not sure why but it keeps killing my browser.

Comment: It kills your browser? I don't think rows is inferior to CSS. If it works it works. Less questions about line height and etc.

Comment: I used the rows attribute because it was an easy way of letting the browser handle the size of making the box big enough... Basically what you want is enough text lines and the rows looked to me like the best way to do it without all the hustle. The alternative is calculating the height yourself witch will take more javascript and cpu. I only tested my solution in Chrome. How did you get it to hang? What browser did you use?

Comment: @Kees I agree. Let the browser figure out what the row height is by itself.

Comment: @AnApprentice changed the code a little bit. Someone gave me an insight into a faster way of doing the up-sizing.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker I've just had to solve the same problem with flickering, and initially went with your solution of adjusting rows using the `scroll` event, but it didn't feel right because `scroll` is usually fired twice (for whatever reason), plus there's a third time due to `keyup`. And it turned out that the best event to use is `input`. This way the adjustment is only done once, and the flickering is solved too. Thanks for pointing the way towards the right event being key!