# How bind the scroll event on a Live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, live, autoresize

A while ago I've solve an issue for someone that [wanted his textarea to grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717635/jquery-building-an-autoresizing-textarea-that-doesnt-flash-on-resize). I've made a function that listens to the `scroll` and `keyup` events of the area and recalculates the number of rows. I wanted to use the code in another project, but there's a problem. The textarea's are not know  To solve this, I'm using `live` instead of `bind`, so that future area's will be bound as well.

Now I'm finding that the `live` executes a lot slower than a `bind`. I've created [a simplified example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/2D8Kf/). The upper textarea behaves as I want, but newly added ones flicker due to the late signaling (I'm using Chrome).

<strike>**How can I make the `live` as fast as the `bind`?**</strike> The problem is that the `scroll` can't be used with a `live` statement. **Is there a way to enable `scroll` for `live`?** Is there maybe a jQuery event that signals me that a new TextArea has been added, so I can use a bind to add the `scroll` on the newly created element?

I'm looking forward to your ideas.

**EDIT:** Changed link to the code. Removed scrollingCode. Added another button to create a different textarea. The problem has to do with 'scroll'. It doesn't fire.

**Clarification:** I will not know what function will create the textarea's. I see flickering on the dynamically added boxes in **Chrome**.

For future readers:

> In jQuery 1.3.x only the following
>   JavaScript events (in addition to
>   custom events) could be bound with
>   .live(): `click, dblclick, keydown,
>   keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove,
>   mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup`. As
>   of jQuery 1.4 the .live() method
>   supports custom events as well as all
>   JavaScript events that bubble. As of
>   jQuery 1.4.1 even focus and blur work
>   with live (mapping to the more
>   appropriate, bubbling, events focusin
>   and focusout). As of jQuery 1.4.1 the
>   hover event can be specified (mapping
>   to mouseenter and mouseleave, which,
>   in turn, are mapped to mouseover and
>   mouseout).

Comment: @Pointy yeah, that's true, that's why I'm making a textarea that will be big enough so it can't scroll. I only scrolls ever so lightly when the user inputs new data and it fires before the keyup. Try and remove the scroll from the example and you'll see that it won't go as smooth.

Comment: @Kees yes I see that after playing with it. Your jsFiddle hangs my browser when I try typing in the "static" textarea, and it works fine I guess when I type in an added textarea. One thing: why does the code call "scrollTop(0)" in the enlarge/reduce loops?

Comment: @Pointy elem.scrollTop(0); can be removed :-). It was from something I was trying :P.

Comment: @Pointy I'm seeing the same performance drop. When I kill the 'live' event the 'bind' does a good job. But with 'bind' and 'live' my browser hangs a bit as well. Werid!

Comment: For what it's worth, it works for me if the "resize" function is re-written to be just: `elem.height(elem.attr('scrollHeight') - elem.attr('clientHeight') + elem.height());`

Comment: Also with that one-line version of "resizeTextArea" I don't see any behavior differences between the "static" textarea and added ones.

Comment: @Pointy, for up sizing you're right, but what about down-sizing ;-)

Comment: Down-sizing does not work for me in any case, old code or new code.

Comment: @Pointy, @Kees - See my updated answer with a short resizing function.

Comment: @galambalazs you can get it even shorter! `elem.height(1); elem.height(elem[0].scrollHeight - elem[0].clientHeight + elem.height());` - that works both for getting bigger and getting smaller.

Comment: @Pointy Yep it's even shorter. :) In any case, the original is too verbose.

Comment: Yes - brilliant insight with the "scroll" problem by the way

Comment: @Pointy Hm. Yours doesn't work in IE, as I've checked it right now: http://jsbin.com/edove4/4/

Comment: @Pointy - Nvm, I've fixed it, and added to the answer. :)

Comment: @galambalazs - ah well I didn't have my windows VM running so I couldn't try it :-)

Comment: @galambalazs @Pointy... thanks for the insights. It makes live easier!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple. `scroll` is what prevents the flickering, because it fires at the very first moment of resize. But `scroll` has no effect with `live` (because it doesn't bubble), so your newly created textareas will be resized on `keyup` but it fires later (thus the flickering).

**Update:** Of course I can even solve your problem. You just need to ask :) **[[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jquery-autoresize/)]**

```
$('textarea.autoresize').live('keyup', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (!el.data("has-scroll")) {
        el.data("has-scroll", true);
        el.scroll(function(){
           resizeTextArea(el);
        });
    }
    resizeTextArea(el);
});
```

The point is, it mixes `live` with `bind`. The `keyup` event, which fires on all elements (because of `live`), adds the unique `scroll` event conditionally.

**Update 2**: Oh, and by the way your whole resizing code can be better written as:

```
// resize text area (fixed version of Pointy's)
function resizeTextArea(elem) {
    elem.height(1); elem.scrollTop(0);
    elem.height(elem[0].scrollHeight - elem[0].clientHeight + elem.height())
}​
```

Comment: ??? Remove the `keyup` from `live` and you'll see that `live("scroll")` is not even called. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html

Comment: Yeah... I see! Is is possible to do some 'live' action to add the scrolling action by hand?

Comment: Well... the problem with the demo was that the static textarea stopped working :-). That's why I wanted to add it to my 'untangled' source hahaha. But it works per-fec-ta-men-to! :D thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @Kees - because  I've accidentally deleted the *initial resize* along with the initial `bind` :) Updated the demo.

Answer (score 2):

[Try this (JSFiddle):](http://jsfiddle.net/HSU6M/2/)

```
$('#Add').click(function(){
    var id = "newtextarea"+Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
   $('#pane').append($('<textarea class="new" rows="1" cols="40" id="'+id+'"></textarea><br/>'));
    $('textarea:last').focus();
    bindAgain(id);
});

//inital resize
resizeTextArea($('#tst'));

//'live' event
$('textarea.new').bind('keyup scroll', function() {
    resizeTextArea($(this));
});

function bindAgain(id)
{
    $('#'+id).bind('keyup scroll', function() {
    resizeTextArea($(this));
});

}
```

Basically, it rebinds the event using a dynamically created ID. Not as elegant as karim79's solution, but it works.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what function is making the textarea. It will be the default behaviour of all the current and future textarea's in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I bind it to a custom event that I call whenever something important happens. Like this:

```
$(body).live('MyCustomEvent', function() {
    $("#MyScrollItem").scroll(function() {
       // Do things here
    }
});
```

Hope that helps. Short and sweet.

Comment: you're correct, but it was already in the section "For future readers" and I quote: "as of jQuery 1.4.1 even focus and blur work with live (mapping to the more appropriate, bubbling, events focusin and focusout). As of jQuery 1.4.1 the hover event can be specified (mapping to mouseenter and mouseleave, which, in turn, are mapped to mouseover and mouseout)." The question was asked for 1.3.*

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that. Guess this may still be of help for future readers as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem: The problem is where .live and scroll doesnt work.

My solution is to use the bind event.. and Timeout. The timeout will give the DOM time to update eg.

The below code is used to load content when you scroll to the bottom of the page. Take a look at the setTimeout and the bind.

```
$('.list').bind("scroll",function(){
    $('.list').height()));
    if($('.list').scrollTop() >= ($('.list').height()+ $(window).height())){        
      setTimeout(function(){    //Time out is used as there is a possibility that
        last_function();
      },200);   
    }
});
```

Comment: Please recheck your code. There may be some extra parentheses.