# autosize textarea width (cols)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a web app for the user to create a simple orgchart. I don't even have the lines connecting the nodes yet, but I am using text areas. I found a very useful autosize() plugin that is great for adding an extra row when the width is taken up. Is there a way to make it so that if the user only uses one line, the autoresize will shrink the width to wrap around the text?

I was trying to figure out how to do the jsfiddle but I dont know how to add more than one javascript (for the plug-in) so Ill just put my jquery code at the bottom of the plug-in and put the plug-in at in the javascript area in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCcGM/1/)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pathway Builder 2.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PathwayBuilder2.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="PathwayBuilder2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plug-ins/autosize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>




<body>
    <div id="Pathway">
        <div class="whole">
            <div class="text_display">
                <textarea class="text_field_not_selected"></textarea><br />
                <input type="button" class="add_child" value="+" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').autosize();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add_child').live({
        click: function() {
            var new_child = '<div class="whole"><div class="text display"><textarea class="text_field_not_selected"></textarea><br /><input type="button" class="add_child not_visable" value="+" /></div></div>';
            $(this).closest('.whole').append(new_child);
            $('.text_field_not_selected').autosize();
        }
    });
});

$('textarea').live('focusin blur', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('text_field_not_selected');
});
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#pathway {
    display: block;
}
.whole {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
textarea {
    min-width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
textarea:focus {
    resize: none;
}
.text_field_not_selected {
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #444;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #444;
}
.add_child {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go **working demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/YVEhr/30/ (more apt)
 **or** http://jsfiddle.net/YVEhr/1/

Please let me know if thats what you want, I am happy to help out. took me a bit to got it (i.e. resizing idea) :)

**Edit** Okies I got it now (Phew) Please feel free to play around with the css or you can have 'row=something` to start with, I have shared some links for further help. :)

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YVEhr/30/

Resizing the textarea to fit the screen: good link: **or** you can also look into this man: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TextFill

**Jquery Code**

```
//inital resize
resizeTextArea($('textarea'));

//resize text area
function resizeTextArea(elem){
   // alert(elem[0].scrollHeight + ' ---- ' + elem[0].clientHeight);
    elem.height(1); 
    elem.scrollTop(0);
    elem.height(elem[0].scrollHeight - elem[0].clientHeight + elem.height());
}

//'live' event
$('textarea').live('keyup', function() {
    var elem = $(this);
   // alert('foo');
    //bind scroll
    if(!elem.data('has-scroll'))
    {
        elem.data('has-scroll', true);
        elem.bind('scroll keyup', function(){
            resizeTextArea($(this));
        });
    }

    resizeTextArea($(this));
});
```

Please let me know if thats what you want.

**Explanation**

Just need to bind new etxtareaclass to `.autosize()` function and rest you can see it in jsfiddle.

Dont forget to accept the answer & if you like you can use this solution without using any plugin: [jQuery - Building an AutoResizing TextArea that Doesn't Flash on Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717635/jquery-building-an-autoresizing-textarea-that-doesnt-flash-on-resize)

Anywho this will work, hope this helps and have a nice one, cheers!

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.add_child').live({
        click: function() {
            var new_child = '<div class="whole"><div class="text display"><textarea class="text_field_not_selected"></textarea><br /><input type="button" class="add_child not_visable" value="+" /></div></div>';
            $(this).closest('.whole').append(new_child);
            $('.text_field_not_selected').autosize();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Aside from appending HTML to the DOM, your thesis is `jQuery('textarea').autosize();` ?

Comment: Hiya @dwerner I added `$('.text_field_not_selected').autosize();` for resizing for the other text area when they get append-ed :), Did I got **or** understood anything wrong. PLease let me know I will correct it, cheers for reply man!

Comment: Hiya @dwerner saweet man thanks for your comment helped me to re-check what is needed, and made the change so that textarea will automatically resizing. Anywho let me know. Thanks again man! **+1**, cheers